# Adding active class not overriding

Tags: css

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple here; I have a collection of `<LI>` elements to which I add a border to on hover (actually change the opacity).

When one of them is selected I user JQuery to add a class "active" to that element. The `.active` class gives the element a blue border. However, if that element is hovered over it still adds the black border as well, or tries.

QUESTION: Can I somehow instruct a `LI` element to only show border if does not have `.active` class?

Here's the CSS I'm trying:

```css
.overview li { border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.0);} /* transparent border */

.overview li:hover{ border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8); } /* show on hover */

.overview li .active { border:1px solid rgba(51,204,204,0.9); } /* change color on active */

.overview li .active:hover { border:1px solid rgba(51,204,204,0.9); } /* trying to force border */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a blank space `" "` too many

```css
.overview li.active { border:1px solid rgba(51,204,204,0.9); } /* change color on active */

.overview li.active:hover { border:1px solid rgba(51,204,204,0.9); } /* trying to force border */
```

Basically, you were looking for any class `active` in the children/grandchildren nodes of `li` and not on the `li` itself.

Comment: Ah b*ll*cks! I knew it was something simple! Thanks so much. Been driving me insane.

Answer (score 4):

`.overview li .active` means "an element which has the class 'active' and is a child of an `li` that is a child of an element with the class 'overview'". You mean "an `li` with the class 'active' that is a child of an element with the class 'overview'".

You need to do `.overview li.active` and `.overview li.active:hover`, removing the extraenous spaces.